How can i show custom error message on my record form in lwc in salesforce if the lastname of the person account is blank?
I want to show a custom error message which says please enter the lastname of the person account if kept empty on the lwc component created using record form
I am expecting a way to show a custom message. My component is showing the lwc validation which are not proper I don’t want to show that and instead want to show a custom error message
 <template if:true={accountRecordId}>
        <div class="slds-p-right_large slds-p-bottom_large">
          <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-m-top_medium">
              <div class="slds-col slds-text-align_right">
          <lightning-button 
            variant="brand"
            label="View" 
            onclick={handleClickNavigate} 
            class="slds-m-top_medium_right"
          ></lightning-button>
          </div> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-p-around_x-small">
           <lightning-record-form
            columns="2"
            object-api-name={objectApiName}
            record-id={accountRecordId}
            fields={fieldsToDisplay}
            mode="view"     
          > 
      </lightning-record-form> 
    </div>

I want to add a custom error message where if the account lastname is null show error for the person account type.

 @api recordId; //Case record ID 
    @track accountRecordId; //This will hold related account Id
    objectApiName = ACCOUNT_OBJECT;
    @track fields = [NAME_FIELD,BUSINESS_TYPE,BUSINESS_SUB_TYPE,SHIPPING_ADDRESS];
    @track fieldsToDisplay = []; //fields based on record type
    @track searchResults = [];
    customErrorMessage = '';

    //wire the case record to get the account id
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [RELATED_ACCOUNT_ID_FIELD] })
    caseRecord({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.accountRecordId = getFieldValue(data, RELATED_ACCOUNT_ID_FIELD);
        } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    //get account details to determine business type
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$accountRecordId', fields: [RECORD_TYPE_ID_FIELD] })
    accountRecord({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
           // const recordTypeId = data.fields.RecordTypeId.value;
           const recordTypeId = getFieldValue(data, RECORD_TYPE_ID_FIELD);

            // Assume that you know the record type ID for person accounts
            const PERSON_ACCOUNT_RECORD_TYPE_ID = 'bshdfbjs'; // Replace with actual record type ID

            if (recordTypeId === PERSON_ACCOUNT_RECORD_TYPE_ID) {
                this.fieldsToDisplay = [NAME_FIELD,BUSINESS_TYPE,PHONE_FIELD,BUSINESS_SUB_TYPE,,EMAIL_FIELD,SHIPPING_ADDRESS];
            } else {
                this.fieldsToDisplay = this.fields;
            }
        } else if (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching account record type:', error);
        }
    }

